# Beginner Ruby Syntax Error with hash

Tags: ruby, hash, hashtable

My code seems to not be working because I'm mishandling a hash...

There's two sections in my code where I reference the hash, and two distinct syntax errors that I haven't resolved through googling.

First Section Syntax Error & Code:

"syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('"

```
def showBoard
    puts "    1  2  3"
    puts " A #{@spaces["A1"]} | #{@spaces["A2"]} | #{@spaces["A3"]}"
    puts ---------------------------
    puts " B #{@spaces["B1"]} | #{@spaces["B2"]} | #{@spaces["B3"]}"
    puts ---------------------------
    puts " C #{@spaces["C1"]} | #{@spaces["C2"]} | #{@spaces["C3"]}"
    puts ---------------------------
end
```

Second Section Syntax Error & Code:

"syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end"

```
def checkGame?
    if 
    "A1"=>"X" && "A2"=>"X" && "A3"=>"X" ||
    "B1"=>"X" && "B2"=>"X" && "B3"=>"X" ||
    "C1"=>"X" && "C2"=>"X" && "C3"=>"X" ||

    "A1"=>"X" && "B1"=>"X" && "C1"=>"X" ||
    "A2"=>"X" && "B2"=>"X" && "C2"=>"X" ||
    "A3"=>"X" && "B3"=>"X" && "C3"=>"X" ||

    "A1"=>"X" && "B2"=>"X" && "C3"=>"X" ||
    "A3"=>"X" && "B2"=>"X" && "C1"=>"X"
        puts player1 + " wins!"
        checkGame == true
    elsif
    "A1"=>"O" && "A2"=>"O" && "A3"=>"O" ||
    "B1"=>"O" && "B2"=>"O" && "B3"=>"O" ||
    "C1"=>"O" && "C2"=>"O" && "C3"=>"O" ||

    "A1"=>"O" && "B1"=>"O" && "C1"=>"O" ||
    "A2"=>"O" && "B2"=>"O" && "C2"=>"O" ||
    "A3"=>"O" && "B3"=>"O" && "C3"=>"O" ||

    "A1"=>"O" && "B2"=>"O" && "C3"=>"O" ||
    "A3"=>"O" && "B2"=>"O" && "C1"=>"O"
        puts player2 + " wins!"
        return true
        checkGame == true
    elsif
    "A1"!=" " && "A2"!=" " && "A3"!= " " &&     
    "B1"!=" " && "B2"!=" " && "B3"!= " " &&
    "C1"!=" " && "C2"!=" " && "C3"!= " "
        puts "It's a draw. :/ "
        checkGame == true
    end

    return false        
end
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the first section is

```
puts -------
```

You probably meant to enclose the dashes in quotes, to make it a string.

The `=>` (hashrocket) operator is only used when declaring a new hash (for example `{"a" => 1}`) but your second bit of code is using it outside of that context ( I'm not sure what you were trying to do so can't really suggest anything). There's a few other things that don't make sense too - you're comparing string literals at the bottom , and I suspect that the precedent of || and && won't do what you want, whatever that is

Comment: ah, duh! to the first one... Thanks for the reply. this is for a game of tic tac toe. For the second bit of code, it's supposed to check for wins in the first if and elsif, and for draw in the last elsif.... I will replace the => with ==